# Distribution of (piece-wise linear) transformed normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, linear-transformations, normal-distribution, density-function

I am trying to solve a probability/statistics problem at work, and it's been a while since I got my hands dirty. So your help will be much appreciated.

Given $n$ normal distributed variables $X_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$, compute the distribution of the $Z$, where:

\begin{equation}
Z = 1/n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i 
\end{equation}

and
$ Y_i = 
 \begin{cases} 
      1 & a\leq X_i  \leq b, \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}.
   \end{cases}
$

with constants $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Are the $X_i$ independent?

Comment: Yes, but not identically distributed. One insight $E(Y_i) = F_{X_i}(b) - F_{X_i}(a)$. But not sure if it is useful.

Comment: You have a good answer but I'll just add two minor bits of information -- you're dealing with a thing called the [Poisson-Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). If you need to do calculations, there's software that will help with this, such as the packages `poibin` and `poisbinom` for R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $X_i$ are independent, then so are the $Y_i$, and $nZ$ is distributed as the sum of $n$ independent Bernouilli rvs, with expectations $p_i =P(a\le X_i\le b)=\Phi((b-\mu_i)/\sigma_i) -\Phi((a-\mu_i)/\sigma_i) $.  The one number that tells the most is the sum $\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i$.  In your applications, is  it tiny, huge, or what?

There is no simple general formula for the distribution of $Z$, but depending on the values of the $p_i$ and $n$, various approximations might be relevant.  Very often, 
the distribution of $nZ$ can be approximated by a Poisson distribution with expectation $\lambda$; 
[Le Cam's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Cam%27s_theorem) bounds the approximation error.  If $n$ is very large and the $p_i$ values are bounded away from $0$ and $1$, a Gaussian distribution might give a better approximation.  (These cases overlap if $\lambda$ is big, so you should work out both.)

For small values of $n$ and given values of the $p_i$ you can work out the theoretical distribution of $nZ$ by mimicking the Pascal Triangle construction.  This computes the convolution of the laws of $Y_1$, of $Y_2$, etc, using an update rule that makes row $i$ from row $i-1$ by adding $1-p_i$ times row $i-1$  plus $p_i$ times the shift of row $i-1$.  When you are done the $n$-th row is $(P(nZ=0), P(nZ=1),\ldots)$.

Without further detail about the ranges of values of $n$ and the $p_i$, and the degree of approximation you are willing to tolerate,  it is hard to give more particular advice.  In one sense the tiny $\lambda$ and huge $\lambda$ cases are more mathematically tractible, and the $\lambda\approx 1$ case harder.

There is a wonderful book on [Poisson Approximation](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/poisson-approximation-9780198522355?cc=us&lang=en&) covering (among other things) cases where the $Y_i$ are dependent.  Depending on details of your problem, some of its results might be applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, in my application $\lambda$ can take on all values in $]0;1[$. Mostly it will be in the range [0.5;0.8], however. The value of $n$ is fairly small. Moreover, $a = -30$ and $b = 30$ are realistic values.I will try to look into some examples to see how well the approximations work out. One follow up questions. What if $X_i$ are dependent?

Comment: Good luck; hope something works out.  I have added a tiny bit to my answer with a reference for dependent situations.

Comment: Ok. One final question. This is maybe a bit tough. How do i compute the probably of observing a specific mean value of $Z$. E.g. let's assume i observe $Z_1$, $Z_2$, and $ Z_3$ and compute $\bar{Z}= 0.5$ as the mean. What is the probability of observing this particular mean value?